# XSLT Add namespace prefix to element best practice

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, prefix

For validation purposes I need to **add namespace prefix to every element** of my transformation result file.
I wrote the transformation below but I think it's not the best way to do what I want and anyway it doesn't work 100%...

On my source file there're **elements without prefix** and I need to add the prefix of the default namespace that is `gmd`. But there're also some other **elements that already have the prefix specified** since they refer to other namespaces such as `gco` and `gml`, and those must be maintained.

Also in some rare cases my input files **could have all the namespace prefixes already set**. So I just want to proceed with the rest of the transformation (for simplicity I have included here only one other template) without adding nothing.

My transformation works but:

1. In the rest of my transformation I need to manipulate some elements to change sub elements order, names and so on... and those elements that match another template, **seems that don't match with the identity template**, so I get them without prefix.
2. I'd like to know how to **improve my code**.

**Source file**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="c:\ISO19139_rve.xsl"?>
<MD_Metadata xmlns="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gmd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gco" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gmd/gmd.xsd">
  <fileIdentifier>
    <gco:CharacterString>b0101011_Vincolo</gco:CharacterString>
  </fileIdentifier>
  <language>
    <gco:CharacterString>IT</gco:CharacterString>
  </language>
  <contact>
    <CI_ResponsibleParty>
      <organizationName>
        <gco:CharacterString>Comune di Conselve (capofila PATI)</gco:CharacterString>
      </organizationName>
      <role>
        <CI_RoleCode codeList="./resource/codeList.xml#CI_RoleCode" codeListValue="Autore">Autore</CI_RoleCode>
      </role>
      <contactInfo>
        <CI_Contact>
          <onlineResource>
            <CI_OnlineResource>
              <linkage>
                <URL>http://www.comune.conselve.it</URL>
              </linkage>
            </CI_OnlineResource>
          </onlineResource>
          <phone>
            <CI_Telephone>
              <voice>
                <gco:CharacterString>0499596511</gco:CharacterString>
              </voice>
            </CI_Telephone>
          </phone>
        </CI_Contact>
      </contactInfo>
      <temporalElement>
        <EX_TemporalExtent>
          <extent>
            <gml:TimePeriod gml:id="tp1">
              <gml:begin>
                <gml:TimeIstant gml:id="ti1">
                  <gml:timePosition>2007-12-01</gml:timePosition>
                </gml:TimeIstant>
              </gml:begin>
              <gml:end>
                <gml:TimeIstant gml:id="ti2">
                  <gml:timePosition>2010-01-01</gml:timePosition>
                </gml:TimeIstant>
              </gml:end>
            </gml:TimePeriod>
          </extent>
        </EX_TemporalExtent>
      </temporalElement>
    </CI_ResponsibleParty>
  </contact>
</MD_Metadata>
```

**XSL transformation**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
    xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gco"
    xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gmd"
    >

    <xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- default: identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="namespace-uri() eq 'http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gmd'">
                <xsl:element name="gmd:{name()}" namespace="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gmd">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
                </xsl:element>    
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>            
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- override: <CI_Contact>, reorder -->
    <xsl:template match="gmd:CI_Contact">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="gmd:phone" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="gmd:address" />

            <xsl:if test="not(gmd:address)">
                <gmd:address>
                    <gmd:CI_Address>
                        <gmd:electronicMailAddress>
                            <gco:CharacterString/>
                        </gmd:electronicMailAddress>
                    </gmd:CI_Address>
                </gmd:address>
            </xsl:if>

            <xsl:copy-of select="gmd:onlineResource" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**My actual result**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="c:\ISO19139_rve.xsl"?>
<gmd:MD_Metadata xmlns="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gmd"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gco"
                 xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
                 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                 xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gmd"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gmd/gmd.xsd">
   <gmd:fileIdentifier>
      <gco:CharacterString>b0101011_Vincolo</gco:CharacterString>
   </gmd:fileIdentifier>
   <gmd:language>
      <gco:CharacterString>IT</gco:CharacterString>
   </gmd:language>
   <gmd:contact>
      <gmd:CI_ResponsibleParty>
         <gmd:organizationName>
            <gco:CharacterString>Comune di Conselve (capofila PATI)</gco:CharacterString>
         </gmd:organizationName>
         <gmd:role>
            <gmd:CI_RoleCode codeList="./resource/codeList.xml#CI_RoleCode" codeListValue="Autore">Autore</gmd:CI_RoleCode>
         </gmd:role>
         <gmd:contactInfo>
            <CI_Contact>
               <gmd:phone>
                  <gmd:CI_Telephone>
                     <gmd:voice>
                        <gco:CharacterString>0499596511</gco:CharacterString>
                     </gmd:voice>
                  </gmd:CI_Telephone>
               </gmd:phone>
               <gmd:address>
                  <gmd:CI_Address>
                     <gmd:electronicMailAddress>
                        <gco:CharacterString/>
                     </gmd:electronicMailAddress>
                  </gmd:CI_Address>
               </gmd:address>
               <onlineResource>
                  <CI_OnlineResource>
                     <linkage>
                        <URL>http://www.comune.conselve.it</URL>
                     </linkage>
                  </CI_OnlineResource>
               </onlineResource>
            </CI_Contact>
         </gmd:contactInfo>
         <gmd:temporalElement>
            <gmd:EX_TemporalExtent>
               <gmd:extent>
                  <gml:TimePeriod gml:id="tp1">
                     <gml:begin>
                        <gml:TimeIstant gml:id="ti1">
                           <gml:timePosition>2007-12-01</gml:timePosition>
                        </gml:TimeIstant>
                     </gml:begin>
                     <gml:end>
                        <gml:TimeIstant gml:id="ti2">
                           <gml:timePosition>2010-01-01</gml:timePosition>
                        </gml:TimeIstant>
                     </gml:end>
                  </gml:TimePeriod>
               </gmd:extent>
            </gmd:EX_TemporalExtent>
         </gmd:temporalElement>
      </gmd:CI_ResponsibleParty>
   </gmd:contact>
</gmd:MD_Metadata>
```

As you can see the transformation works only for elements that are not matched by another template. Look at the result for `<CI_Contact>`, `<onlineResource>`, `<CI_OnlineResource>`, etc.

Comment: What kind of validation is that when you say "For validation purposes I need to add namespace prefix to every element of my transformation result file."? Normal schema based validation checks the namespace of nodes but not the prefixes as they don't matter, an element `<foo xmlns="http://example.com/">...</foo>` is as valid as `<pf:foo xmlns:pf="http://example.com/">...</foo>`.

Comment: [This](http://inspire-geoportal.ec.europa.eu/validator2/) is the INSPIRE standard validation. And also the GeoNetwork metadata import tool.

Answer (score 3):

I would write

```
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="namespace-uri() eq 'http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gmd'">
            <xsl:element name="gmd:{name()}" namespace="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gmd">
                <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
            </xsl:element>    
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>            
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

as two templates

```
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
            </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="gmd:*">
    <xsl:element name="gmd:{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gmd">
                <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
     </xsl:element>    

</xsl:template>
```

But of course if you have other templates matching and transforming elements in the `http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gmd` namespace then you need to make sure the prefix change is done in them as well, e.g.

```
<!-- override: <CI_Contact>, reorder -->
<xsl:template match="gmd:CI_Contact">
    <xsl:element name="gmd:{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gmd">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="gmd:phone" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="gmd:address" />

        <xsl:if test="not(gmd:address)">
            <gmd:address>
                <gmd:CI_Address>
                    <gmd:electronicMailAddress>
                        <gco:CharacterString/>
                    </gmd:electronicMailAddress>
                </gmd:CI_Address>
            </gmd:address>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:copy-of select="gmd:onlineResource" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Your solution works fine on this sample XML file, but placing it on my original transformation get me some elements with declaration of **all namespaces** inside... So, another solution I found is to replace the root element on each template. So instead of: `<xsl:template match="gmd:CI_Contact">
    <xsl:element name="gmd:{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gmd">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />...` as you wrote, I used instead: `<xsl:template match="gmd:CI_Contact">
    <gmd:CI_Contact>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />...`